# Scala spark: Sum all columns across all rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I can do this quite easily with

```
df.groupBy().sum()
```

But I'm not sure if the `groupBy()` doesn't add additional performance impacts, or is just bad style. I've seen it done with

```
df.agg( ("col1", "sum"), ("col2", "sum"), ("col3", "sum"))
```

Which skips the (I think unnecessary groupBy), but has its own uglyness. What's the correct way to do this? Is there any under-the-hood difference between using `.groupBy().<aggOp>()` and using `.agg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the **`Physical plan`** for both queries spark internally calls same plan so we can use either of them!

I think using **`df.groupBy().sum()`** will be handy as we don't need to specify all column names.

**`Example:`**

```
val df=Seq((1,2,3),(4,5,6)).toDF("id","j","k")

scala> df.groupBy().sum().explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[sum(cast(id#7 as bigint)), sum(cast(j#8 as bigint)), sum(cast(k#9 as bigint))])
+- Exchange SinglePartition
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_sum(cast(id#7 as bigint)), partial_sum(cast(j#8 as bigint)), partial_sum(cast(k#9 as bigint))])
      +- LocalTableScan [id#7, j#8, k#9]

scala> df.agg(sum("id"),sum("j"),sum("k")).explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[sum(cast(id#7 as bigint)), sum(cast(j#8 as bigint)), sum(cast(k#9 as bigint))])
+- Exchange SinglePartition
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_sum(cast(id#7 as bigint)), partial_sum(cast(j#8 as bigint)), partial_sum(cast(k#9 as bigint))])
      +- LocalTableScan [id#7, j#8, k#9]
```